# PredictionIO and Recommendation Template Files

Tags: recommendation-engine, predictionio

i'm trying to build movie recommendation application using PredictionIO.
i have already using PredictionIO 0.11 on **Docker**, the issue
 that when i run `pio build --verbose` it's showing:

```
no engine found. your build might have failed. aborting.
```

not sure where to puts the recommendation template files?.
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that you are in the current working directory of your engine I mean you have to execute your pio build --verbose command from the directory where your templates's engine.json file is placed . If this not solves your issue can you please paste the complete error along with template link.